# How to change the socket.io port per transport?

Tags: socket.io

is it possible to specify the socket.io port for different transports? something like this  (without creating a different socket per port)

```
var socket = new io.Socket('', {
    'port': '80',
    'transports': ['websocket', 'xhr-polling'],
    'transportOptions': {
         'websocket': {'port': '80' },
         'xhr-polling': {'port': '8000' }
     }
});
```